# change ip with tampermonkey or greasemonkey from browser

Tags: javascript, proxy, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

How does one change IP address using javascript on keyboard shortcut pressed? I am using tampermonkey/firefox.

The code would look something like this:

```
document.onkeydown = keydown;

function keydown(evt){
  if (!evt) evt = event;
  if (evt.metaKey && evt.keyCode==68){ //CMD+d
      // change IP address here, possibly using proxys or some other way

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this isn't possible. It is beyond JavaScript's capabilities to change an IP adress. (see [this webpage for more info](http://forums.devshed.com/javascript-development-115/change-ip-javascript-552515.html)).

To do this you would need to use something like C++. JavaScript doesn't have the ability to communicate with the wireless router.

Comment: I've been to that website and I didn't like the answer. :) So any example on how to change IP programatically?

Comment: yes you did. Thank you for that. I actually meant an example with c++.  All the answers are between 6-10 years old. I am on a mac.

Comment: do you think that [this](https://00f.net/2011/08/14/programmatically-changing-network-configuration-on-osx/) website would help?